# Android: use animation outside the view area

Tags: android, animation, area

I have an xml with 12 image. for example 3*4 table, where each cell contains an image.
In the OnCreate I write animation every image:

```
AnimationSet set = new AnimationSet(true);
        Animation animation = new TranslateAnimation(
                Animation.ABSOLUTE, -300.0f, Animation.START_ON_FIRST_FRAME, 0.0f,
            Animation.ABSOLUTE, -800.0f, Animation.START_ON_FIRST_FRAME, 0.0f);

        animation.setFillBefore(true);
        animation.setFillAfter(true);
        animation.setFillEnabled(true);
        animation.setDuration(5000);
```

I want to start the animation from the top left of the screen and to end the animation to real position. But the animation is only use the image or cell region. Is there any solution to the animation, use the whole screen?

Answer (score 4):

If they're all under the same parent view, you can set the parent's clipChildren attribute to false, which would allow the animation to extend beyond its own constraints (as long as it still remains within the boundaries of its parent):

```
android:clipChildren="false"
```